# jquery.floatThead causes header to become blurry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ in a Bootstrap site. However when I use the script, my header becomes blurry as below.

[image]

When I inspect it, I see that there is a style applied. If I remove it, it clears it up but then the header/row goes out of sight. The CSS is:

```
transform: translateX(15px) translateY(362px);
```

[image]

How do I get rid of the text being blurry?

**HTML**

```
<table id="alternate" class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th>Date Ordered</th>
            <th>Quantity Ordered</th>
            <th>Quantity Dispatched</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>...
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    var $tableAlternate = $('table#alternate');
    $tableAlternate.floatThead({top: 51});
    $tableAlternate.floatThead();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if your browser zoom is at 100%? I had similar issue on MS Edge and my browser zoom was at 90%. Changing it 100% fixed the issue for me.